# Bash script to hide/show files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, osx, osx-finder

I prepared a little bash script to toggle the visibility of my hidden OS X files.

```
if (defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE); then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
elif (defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE); then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
fi

killall Finder
```

When hidden files are invisible, the script successfully makes them visible but afterwards, when I re-run the script to make the hidden files invisible again, it fails and does nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding debug information to 'see' what the script thinks it is doing? Did you try running it with the dash x option (e.g. change the first two lines to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and the second line to `set -x`).

Comment: I got the following output                                + defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
+ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
+ killall Finder                                         It seems the if-else part is not working at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `if` conditions you should use the `defaults read` command, and not `write`. Otherwise the result is always true and of course the `elif` never runs.

Also, that is not the syntax for `if` conditions. You should use:

```
if [ $(command) == "TRUE" ]; then
```

But in this case, perhaps something like this would be less verbose:

```
STATUS=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)
case "$STATUS" in
    "TRUE") OPTION="FALSE" ;;
    "FALSE") OPTION="TRUE" ;;
esac
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles $OPTION

killall Finder
```

Comment: That read/write situation came to my mind as well yesterday after debugging. Nice spotting. Thanks for your solution as well. You've been very helpful.